# When I execute the following code, there is no output, what could be the cause?

Tags: c, output

Here is my C code. I am not getting any output. Please help. I also tried adding the initialization of inside the main function, then also I  am not getting any output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 10;
int main()
{
    if (x = 20)
    {
        x = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("x not eqaul to 20\n");
    }
    if (x > 0)
    {
       printf("x not greather than 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        /* notjing */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (x = 20)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me

Comment: @GSerg `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Add some `print`s to each `if` and each `else` branch and see what happens.

Comment: x=20 is an assignment. x==20 is a comparison operator. The result of x=20 is 20 which is a number not equal to zero so this condition is correct. x==20 will give 0 or false for x=10 because its  comparison operator. So it goes inside first if and now x=-1. After this x>0 is not true and we go inside the last else block and then over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the first `if`-statement you wrote `if(x=20)`.  This is not a conditunal argument, this is a mathematical operand.

So `x` will be set to 20; afterworths it will be set to -1. And no `printf()` will be called.

If think you wanted to use `if(x==20)`.

Comment: It's not a 'mathematical operand' but rather an assignment expression.